# Get current active window's title in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, active-window

I am trying to write a Java program that logs what application I'm using every 5 seconds (this is a time tracker app). I need some way to find out what the current active window is. I found KeyboardFocusManager.getGlobalActiveWindow() but I can't get it to work right. A cross platform solution is preferable, but if one doesn't exist, then I'm developing for linux with X.Org. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a windowing system like KDE or Gnome? It may be necessary to know that since this kind of task usually needs to be done with system-specific code.

Answer (score 7):

I'm quite certain that you'll find there's no way to enumerate the active windows in pure Java (I've looked pretty hard before), so you'll need to code for the platforms you want to target.

- On Mac OS X, you can launch an [AppleScript](http://lists.apple.com/archives/AppleScript-Users/2008/Jun/msg00395.html) using "osascript".
- On X11, you can use [xwininfo](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.os.linux.x/2005-08/0061.html).
- On Windows, you can probably launch some VBScript (e.g. [this link](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/3879dd1b-09a1-4a9f-95ca-529351a7e2ac) looks promising).

If you're using SWT, you may be able to find some undocumented, non-public methods in the SWT libs, since SWT provides wrappers for a lot of the OS API's (e.g. SWT on Cocoa has the `org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS#objc_msgSend()` methods that can be used to access the OS). The equivalent "OS" classes on Windows and X11 may have API's you can use.

Answer (score 4):

I have written a java program using user361601's script. I hope this will help others.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class WindowAndProcessInfo4Linux {

public static final String WIN_ID_CMD = "xprop -root | grep " + "\"_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)\"" + "|cut -d ' ' -f 5";
public static final String WIN_INFO_CMD_PREFIX = "xwininfo -id ";
public static final String WIN_INFO_CMD_MID = " |awk \'BEGIN {FS=\"\\\"\"}/xwininfo: Window id/{print $2}\' | sed \'s/-[^-]*$//g\'";

public String execShellCmd(String cmd){
    try {  

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();  
        Process process = runtime.exec(new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", cmd });  
        int exitValue = process.waitFor();  
        System.out.println("exit value: " + exitValue);  
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));  
        String line = "";  
        String output = "";
        while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
            output = line;
        }
        return output;
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }  
}

public String windowInfoCmd(String winId){
    if(null!=winId && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(winId)){
        return WIN_INFO_CMD_PREFIX+winId +WIN_INFO_CMD_MID;
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main (String [] args){
    WindowAndProcessInfo4Linux windowAndProcessInfo4Linux = new WindowAndProcessInfo4Linux();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String winId = windowAndProcessInfo4Linux.execShellCmd(WIN_ID_CMD);
    String winInfoMcd = windowAndProcessInfo4Linux.windowInfoCmd(winId);
    String windowTitle = windowAndProcessInfo4Linux.execShellCmd(winInfoMcd);
    System.out.println("window title is: "+ windowTitle);

}
}
```

// the thread.sleep is there so that you get time to switch to other window :)
also, you may use quartz from spring to schedule it.

Answer (score 3):

Using SWT internals, I was able to put this together, and it seems to work nicely:

```java
    /** @return The currently active window's title */
    public static final String getActiveWindowText() {
        long /*int*/ handle = OS.GetForegroundWindow();
        int length = OS.GetWindowTextLength(handle);
        if(length == 0) return "";
        /* Use the character encoding for the default locale */
        TCHAR buffer = new TCHAR(0, length + 1);
        OS.GetWindowText(handle, buffer, length + 1);
        return buffer.toString(0, length);
    }
```

```java
public static final void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    System.out.println(getActiveWindowText());
}
```

Prints: `user interface - Get current active window's title in Java - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome`

Comment: One thing I should note, this is using the Windows-specific SWT librariy, and so it won't work on other platforms.
You might be able to do what I did and open up the other SWT platform libraries and construct a version of this function for your desired platform.

Answer (score 2):

To find the active Window(be it a frame or a dialog) in a java swing application you can use the following recursive method:

```
Window getSelectedWindow(Window[] windows) {
    Window result = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
        Window window = windows[i];
        if (window.isActive()) {
            result = window;
        } else {
            Window[] ownedWindows = window.getOwnedWindows();
            if (ownedWindows != null) {
                result = getSelectedWindow(ownedWindows);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

this is from [here](http://www.rojotek.com/blog/rob/archives/000060.html)
More clues on Window state [here](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3502181).

Comment: That only takes Java windows into account, though, whereas I think Steven wants to get the globally active window, whether it's a Java program or not.

Comment: Oops! I misunderstood the question!

Comment: David is right, I want to know the name of the globally active window. That way I can automatically keep track of when I use, say, firefox, and when I use, say, Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a bash script that logs the current active window:
http://www.whitelamp.com/public/active-window-logger.html
It uses a patched version of wmctrl but provides details of 
an alternative (slower) method using xprop and xwininfo.

The links to the wmctrl patch & source code and the script can be 
found above.

Answer (score -1):

I created this applescript while looking into similar topic - this one gets the specific window size

```html
global theSBounds

tell application "System Events"
 set this_info to {}
 set theSBounds to {}
 repeat with theProcess in processes
  if not background only of theProcess then
   tell theProcess
    set processName to name
    set theWindows to windows
   end tell
   set windowsCount to count of theWindows
   
   if processName contains "xxxxxxxx" then
    set this_info to this_info & processName
    
   else if processName is not "Finder" then
    if windowsCount is greater than 0 then
     repeat with theWindow in theWindows
      tell theProcess
       tell theWindow
        if (value of attribute "AXTitle") contains "Genymotion for personal use -" then
         -- set this_info to this_info & (value of attribute "AXTitle")
         set the props to get the properties of the theWindow
         set theSBounds to {size, position} of props
         set this_info to this_info & theSBounds
        end if
       end tell
      end tell
     end repeat
    end if
   end if
  end if
 end repeat
end tell
return theSBounds
```

Comment: Please also provide explanation for your code instead of just pasting it here.